# What Does mysqli_store_result() Actually Do?

Tags: php, mysqli, mysqli-multi-query

I want to understand that What **`mysqli_store_result`** Actually does? When I visited the [PHP Manual](http://pk1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.store-result.php) of `mysqli_store_result`, I found the definiton

```
mysqli_store_result — Transfers a result set from the last query
```

The Question is Where it transfers the result set? 
Actually I was getting the error `"Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"` after executing `mysqli_multi_query` But When I used the following method, the Error gone.

```
 mysqli_multi_query($connection,$query);

do
{
    mysqli_store_result($connection);
}
while(mysqli_next_result($connection));
```

Now, Should I use this `mysqli_store_result($connection)` and `mysqli_next_result($connection)` after each `mysqli_query` or just after `mysqli_multi_query` Because I have read in PHP Manaul that

> "Although it is always good practice to free the memory used by the
>   result of a query using the mysqli_free_result() function, when
>   transferring large result sets using the mysqli_store_result() this
>   becomes particularly important."

Source: [PHP: mysqli_store_result](http://pk1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.store-result.php#refsect1-mysqli.store-result-notes)

One More Question Arises When I executed the above mentioned `mysqli_multi_query($connection,$query);` I put a statement `echo 'storing result <br />'` like below

```
do
{
    echo 'storing result <br />
    mysqli_store_result($connection);
}
while(mysqli_next_result($connection));
```

Although There were only Two INSERT queries in the $query but It gave the following output

```
storing result
storing result
storing result
storing result
```

It means there were four result sets that were transferred. I can't understand this situation. 
One Last Question. Does the above mentioned `do while` process will effect the performance?

Comment: Please post your `$query` string that produces the unexpected result.

Answer (score 7):

Previous comments have stated that `mysqli_store_result()` is not to be used with INSERT statements, but no one has mentioned the actual appropriate function: `mysqli_affected_rows()`.
If your statement returns a record set and you want to check it numerically, then use `mysqli_num_rows()`.

If dealing with a mixture, this might get you started:

```
$queries[] = "INSERT INTO TestTable (Column1) VALUES ('TEST1')";
$queries[] = "SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE Column1 LIKE 'TEST%'";
$queries[] = "INSERT INTO TestTable (Column1) VALUES ('TEST2')";
$queries[] = "SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE Column1 LIKE 'TEST%'";
$queries[] = "DELETE FROM TestTable WHERE Column1 LIKE 'TEST%'";

if(mysqli_multi_query($con, implode(';', $queries))){
    do{
        if($result = mysqli_store_result($con)){
            echo "Selected rows = " . mysqli_num_rows($result) . "<br><br>";
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }else{
            $cumulative_rows += $aff_rows = mysqli_affected_rows($con);
            echo "Current Query's Affected Rows = $aff_rows, Cumulative Rows = $cumulative_rows<br><br>";
        }
    } while(mysqli_more_results($con) && mysqli_next_result($con));
}
```

Outputs:

```
Current Query's Affected Rows = 1, Cumulative Affected Rows = 1

Selected rows = 1

Current Query's Affected Rows = 1, Cumulative Affected Rows = 2

Selected rows = 2

Current Query's Affected Rows = 2, Cumulative Affected Rows = 4
```

*An important note to anyone new to the topic of database querying:  If you are using user-supplied / externally-sourced / untrustworthy data, then you should be using prepared statements with placeholders for security/stability (**`mysqli_multi_query()` DOES NOT AFFORD THIS**).  Using `mysqli_multi_query()` seems like a cool, concise way to send a batch of queries, but there are not many compelling reasons/scenarios to use this function over sending queries one-at-a-time in a secure manner.*

Comment: @Munib if my answer satisfies your question please award it the green tick.  If something is still unclear, leave me a comment and I'll try to fix up my answer.  Let's get a resolution on this question.

Answer (score 0):

It actually  will fetch the whole resultset from the MySQL. You can then mysqli_data_seek() to move to a particular row within the set. So that means all of the results will be stored on the php-side after the first call, and subsequent calls will just request the results from php

Comment: But What Result Set could be after an INSERT INTO Statement. Another Question, It is performance effective?

Comment: If you have several queries to execute with an unknown number of rows, you will experience a definite and important increase in efficiency, as well as a lowering of the total workload on the server - particularly if you are doing all of this on a single box.

Comment: For insert I don't think you need to store. You can store results which are very constant like in case of a simple implementation list of countries which you want from db, this result you can store in store_result variable and then use it so that you don't need to make calls

Comment: Is there any way to check the result set after using `mysqli_store_result`. I mean can I check that what is the size of the result set that is stored.

Comment: use mysql_seek_set instead to check